# html DOM generation and html regeneration out of DOM

Tags: html, dom, visual-c++

I want to get the html content of an html file and modify some areas (actually I want to translate the text in the html page )and then REBUILD the new html file out of my modified DOM tree.Can anybody please show me the way how I can do that ?I have found html DOM parsers,but they dont regenerate the modified html file for  me .they just give me the DOM and I can modify the text nodes to things which I want but I can not have the new html file.

Thank you for your notice.
Mehrnaz

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery's $.html function.  You may be able to do something along the lines of:

```
var newbody = '<div>Translated text</div><div>More translated text</div>';
$('body').html(newbody);
```

This function replaces everything inside the `<body>` tag with your new contents.